# Q:How to migrate Project from RapidClipse4 to RapidClipseX?

Tags: java, migration, vaadin, rapidclipse

I would like to migrate my Project from RapidClipse4 to RapidClipseX.
I tried to open the RC4-project in RC-X (by loading the RC4 workspace into RC-X)
and I tried to import the RC4-project into a new RC-X project.

In both cases I still miss my project structure, the entities and dao's.
Or I still miss the well known Project structure out of RC4.
I tried also several perspectives without success.

As a following problem I still got some errors in the project.
(The errors are not specified in this question, because I assume the reason is based on how I handled the imports)

I searched for manuals/ howTo's without success.

Has anyone expierience?
Did anyone have something like a migration manual?

Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you in advance
rgds OpaHeinz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project structure of RapidClipse 4 has changed drastically in RapidClipse X. The UI Layer has seen many changes as well.

The best way to migrate is to create a new project using RapidClipse X and then copying over all business/db classes into the new project.

The UI you have to rebuild from scratch. So what I would do is open the old views in RC4 and then recreating them in RCX

Resources used by the server can be best stored in "src/main/resources", and for client resources like images "src/main/webapp/frontend"

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a try.
I got the hint from RapidClipse support, that they will create something like a migration manual. rgds OpaHeinz